# application angular 6 not displaying browser console error Cannot GET /secure/bootstrap-data

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

I was asked to do modifications on Angular 6 web application i'didn't know until now . I received a sourcecode but i tried to display the website and i doesn't work. I stayed late at night and wake up early in morning just to make ng serve succesful. I'v been correcting browser console errors too. It seems this source code is not working. But now i'm stuck. I can't find the problem on the net. The browser console error is

> Response : error Cannot GET /secure/bootstrap-data

It' for an GET http request. I cannot say if a module is lacking or something. I'm just 2 months experimented in angular.

here is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "tickets",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4500",
    "build": "ng build --source-map=false --prod --deploy-url=client/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.1.6",
    "@ctrl/ngx-csv": "^1.1.6",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.32",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/pikaday": "^1.6.3",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "brace": "^0.10.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "chartist-plugin-legend": "^0.6.2",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "deepmerge": "^2.1.0",
    "dot-object": "^1.7.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-csv": "^0.3.6",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.3",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.6.0",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "pikaday": "^1.7.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.6.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
    "raven-js": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "svg4everybody": "^2.1.9",
    "tinymce": "^4.5.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.6",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.42",
    "@types/deepmerge": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/dot-object": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.112",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.4",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.0.8",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^1.2.3",
    "gulp-svgstore": "^6.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

thanks.

EDIT

More information with web browser :

error in bootstrapper.service.ts : line 65

```
/**
     * Bootstrap application with data returned from server.
     */
    public bootstrap(data?: string): Promise<any> {
        if ( ! data) data = window['bootstrapData'];

        // if we have bootstrap data in global scope, pass
        // it to the app and return self resolving promise
        if (data) {
            this.handleData(data);
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
        }

        // fetch bootstrap data from backend and return promise that
        // resolves once request is complete and data is passed to the app
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = this.settings.getBaseUrl() + 'secure/bootstrap-data';
            this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
                this.handleData(response['data']);
                resolve();
            }, error => {
                console.log('bootstrap error', error);
                reject();
            });
        });
```

line 65 refers to console.log('bootstrap error', error).
It seems to be Ajax Request.

Found the entire service. It seems to be call at launch :

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Settings} from './config/settings.service';
import {Translations} from './translations/translations.service';
import {APP_CONFIG, VebtoConfig} from './config/vebto-config';
import {Role} from './types/models/Role';
import {User} from './types/models/User';
import { LocalizationWithLines } from './types/localization-with-lines';
import { CurrentUser } from '../auth/current-user';
import { AppearanceListenerService } from '../shared/appearance/appearance-listener.service';

export function init_app(bootstrapper: Bootstrapper) {
    return () => bootstrapper.bootstrap();
}

export interface BootstrapData {
    csrf_token: string;
    settings: VebtoConfig;
    guests_role: Role|null;
    user: User|null;
    i18n?: LocalizationWithLines;
}

@Injectable()
export class Bootstrapper {
    protected http: HttpClient;
    protected settings: Settings;
    protected currentUser: CurrentUser;
    protected i18n: Translations;
    public data: BootstrapData;

    constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
        this.http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);
        this.settings = this.injector.get(Settings);
        this.currentUser = this.injector.get(CurrentUser);
        this.i18n = this.injector.get(Translations);

        // merge all config provided by modules into single object
        this.injector.get(APP_CONFIG).forEach(providedConfig => {
            return this.settings.merge({vebto: providedConfig});
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap application with data returned from server.
     */
    public bootstrap(data?: string): Promise<any> {
        if ( ! data) data = window['bootstrapData'];

        // if we have bootstrap data in global scope, pass
        // it to the app and return self resolving promise
        if (data) {
            this.handleData(data);
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
        }

        // fetch bootstrap data from backend and return promise that
        // resolves once request is complete and data is passed to the app
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = this.settings.getBaseUrl() + 'secure/bootstrap-data';
            this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
                this.handleData(response['data']);
                resolve();
            }, error => {
                console.log('bootstrap error', error);
                reject();
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Handle specified bootstrap data.
     */
    protected handleData(encodedData: string): BootstrapData {
        // decode bootstrap data from server
        const data = JSON.parse(atob(encodedData)) as BootstrapData;

        // set csrf token
        this.settings.csrfToken = data.csrf_token;

        // set all settings returned from server
        this.settings.setMultiple(data.settings);

        // set translations
        if (data.i18n) {
            this.i18n.setLocalization(data.i18n);
        }

        // set current user and default role for guests
        this.currentUser.init({
            guestsRole: data.guests_role,
            user: data.user,
        });

        // init appearance editor mode if needed
        this.injector.get(AppearanceListenerService).init();

        this.data = data;

        return data;
    }
}
```

AFTER RESEARCHES

All http requests in the code are used with prefix 'secure'
and i have this proxy.conf.json file :

```
{
  "/secure": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/__clockwork": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

but it's not redirecting HTTP GET Request in browser console : http://localhost:4200/secure/bootsrap-data !

Comment: the code was given to me and it was supposed to work. Maybe a bootstrap module is missing ?

Comment: check where in your code there're a `this.http.get`, posible you need add a file to your assets folder or your app need an API, but really I don't know (I've never heard about secure/bootstrap-data)

Comment: it's a url from backend according to comments (it's laravel backend). But backend is with port 8000 not 4200 like in the http request there is a problem with the code no ?

Comment: You has a problem with the getURLBase(), I imagine you use the "APP_CONFIG". check the files under `./config` (also check the` /src/environments/` files) in any place you say in what direction is your API

Comment: in fact there is a proxy.conf.json file. It's supposed to redirect http client request because they all have "secure" prefix but it doesn't seem to work. Content :     "/secure": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8000",
    "secure": false
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just used the ng serve command :

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

because it wasn't taking in account the proxy file to redirect to backend when the url was starting with /secure/*.